# Loading a javascript file from another javascript file on angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am developing an application using Angular. I have a scenario where I have to a JavaScript file named "myclass.js" which contains a certain function.  Now I need to call this function from another JavaScript file (main.js).

myclass.js

```
export class myclass{
    showMessage(){
        alert("This is a message");
    }
}
```

main.js

```
 import { myclass } './myclass.js';
 
 function testMessage(){
     c = new myclass();
     c.showMessage();
 }
```

When trying to run the script the following error is displayed.

```
Uncaught Syntax Error: Can not use a import statement outside a module.
```

Can someone help to sort it out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create an instance of `myClass` class

Comment: Tried that.. but the error happens in the import statement.. Its not reach testMessage function

Comment: Define type as module in package.json, or rename to main.mjs.